# Microsoft access import all email from in all folder from outlook

Tags: excel, import, outlook

I want to import in access all email in all folder from outlook. what i could do is just to import from a specific folder, but I want to import all email containing in all folder.

Answer (score 1):

If you can import emails from a single folder then you know how to get the job done. You just need to iterate through all folders and run the code against each folder in the tree. See [How to: Enumerate Folders](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff184607.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for the sample code.